# Return Only Duplicate Records After Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `users` table and an `emails` table.  A user can have many emails.

I want to grab only those users that have more than one email.  Here is what  I have so far:

```
SELECT Users.name, emails.email
FROM Users
INNER JOIN emails
On Users.id=Emails.user_id
/*specify condition to only grab duplicates here */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN emails e On u.id = e.user_id
group by u.id 
having count(distinct e.email) > 1
```

Use `group by` and `having`

Comment: would it be better to group_by users.id in the situation where users.name is not unique?  There might be multiple users with the same name.

Comment: sure..that is always better.

Comment: what is the point of `distinct` in the count aggregate function?  Why is that needed?

Comment: It is because, if a user has the same email address on all the rows, this query wouldn't return that user. As he has only one email id, which was the question.

Comment: my question was about grabbing only those users that have more than one email.   Example: user with id `1` has three emails: foo@xyz.com, bar@xyz.com, and bazz@xyz.com.  I would grab him.  whereas I would not grab user with id `2` who only has one email, or user with id `3` who has no emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Users.name, emails.email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emails.email ORDER BY emails.email) AS 'Rank' 
FROM Users
INNER JOIN emails
On Users.id=Emails.user_id)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Rank > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to count for the total number of emails in a seperate subquery that returns the user_id of those users having more than one emails.

```
SELECT users.name, emails.email
FROM users
INNER JOIN emails
ON users.id = emails.user_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM emails
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) _cc
ON users.id = _cc.user_id;
```

UPDATE: If you only need the user_id without the additional emails you can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(emails.user_id)
FROM users
INNER JOIN emails
ON users.id = emails.user_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM emails
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) _cc
ON users.id = _cc.user_id;
```

Lets say we have the data below:

```
USERS
id name
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
5  E

EMAILS
id user_id email
1  1       email 1
2  1       email 2
3  2       email 3
4  2       email 2
5  3       email 5
```

So using the above data the results of the two queries will be:

QUERY 1

```
name email
A    email 1
A    email 2
B    email 3
B    email 4
```

QUERY 2

```
user_id
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are grouping by emails and showing those that have a count > 1

```
SELECT Users.name, emails.email
FROM Users
INNER JOIN emails
On Users.id=Emails.user_id 

GROUP BY emails.email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```